# LaTeXiT 2.9.0: exporting does not work properly when the file include "/"

Tags: naming, export, latexit

LaTeXiT2.9.0, macOS High Sierra.

Recently, LaTeXiT2.9.0 has changed the setting of filename when you drag the formula.
It was like 'latex-image-1.pdf' previously, however, now uses codes as a name, for instance 'frac_gamma_3_.pdf' from \frac{\gamma}{3}.

The problem is happening when we use "/" for example "1/2". This kind of formula, even simple 1/2, does not generate any type of files though it is compiled.

What should I do in order to export the formulae with "/"?

Comment: That's a problem! Go to the LaTeXiT web site and let the author know.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, Herb Schulz.
I have just mailed him about this problem.

Comment: Now, Pierre replied me to use beta version of 2.9.1.
It is fixed! I will use this version for a while. This is a link:
https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-beta.php